# Two variables for ffmpeg; use for loop?

Tags: bash, for-loop, ffmpeg

I would like to silence sequences in a number of audio files with ffmpeg, which requires to give two variables, the starting point and the end point.

It works nice when you add the two variables in a script like so

```
echo "which file do you want to silence"
read filename

echo "When does the muted period start in seconds"
read A

echo "When does the muted period end in seconds"
read B

ffmpeg -i $filename -af "volume=enable='between(t,$A,$B)':volume=0" output_silenced.mp3
```

I have read all the "similar questions" that come up in a search for "use two variables in bash" and similar search terms, but I can't get my head around this.

I put the variables in two files, with new lines for each number, and tried to call the files in a for loop, which did not work. I also tried to call them in a for loop like so

```
echo "which file do you want to silence"
read filename

for A in 22 33 57; do

for B in 27 45.5 58.5; do

ffmpeg -i $filename -af "volume=enable='between(t,$A,$B)':volume=0" output_silenced.mp3

mv output_silenced.mp3 filename.mp3
done
done
```

but the output sounds just like the original input audio!

Can anybody help me out with this? I have to partly silence many files and it already takes forever to figure out all the start and end moments, and it would be great to get through with this a bit easier!

Thanks a lot in advance!